# Name range assignment from filtered data

Tags: excel, range

I am running into a problem. I am trying to assign the ListBox rowsource to a range that is filtered. I can make it work copying the filtered range to a new sheet and later assign a name to this range but I don't want to create an extra sheet only for this purpose. This is my code. It is not perfect because I am not a professional programmer but this is driving me crazy. Everything works except that filtered range is not being assigned to the range name.

```
      If pairfilter.Value <> "" Then

         ' APPLY FILTER TO CURRENCY PAIR
         .Range("G2").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=pairfilter.Value, VisibleDropDown:=True

      End If

      If wlbfilter.Value <> "" Then

         ' APPLY FILTER TO WIN-LOSS-BREAKEVEN
         .Range("Y2").AutoFilter Field:=25, Criteria1:=wlbfilter.Value, VisibleDropDown:=True

      End If

      If lsfilter.Value <> "" Then

          ' APPLY FILTER TO LONG-SHORT
          .Range("D2").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=lsfilter.Value, VisibleDropDown:=True

      End If

      If signalfilter.Value <> "" Then

          ' APPLY FILTER TO SIGNALS
          .Range("AD2").AutoFilter Field:=30, Criteria1:=signalfilter.Value, VisibleDropDown:=True

      End If

      If structurefilter.Value <> "" Then

          ' APPLY FILTER TO STRUCTURE
          .Range("AE2").AutoFilter Field:=31, Criteria1:=structurefilter.Value, VisibleDropDown:=True

      End If

      ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter

       lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
       Set ws = Sheets(2)
       ws.Activate
       With ws
       Range("A1", Range("AH" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Name = "Dynamic1"
       Me.tradelist.RowSource = "Dynamic1"
       Me.tradelist.ListIndex = 1
       TabStrip1.Value = 0
      End With
```

Comment: You must use a contiguous range if you want to fill a listbox.

Comment: Thank you Tim, so, there is no way to assign the filtered range to a name which is the source of the listbox? What would be the best approach for this?Thank you

Comment: The easiest approach is to copy to another sheet and use that - you can hide the sheet if you don't want it visible...

Comment: Thank you Tim, I think that is what I am going to do: hide the worksheet and done. Thank you again